# Creating a GitHub Project Page for a repository owned by an organization

Tags: github

I created a [GitHub Project Page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#project-pages) for my project, storing it in the `gh-pages` branch, as instructed. It was located at the following URL: `[username].github.io/[project_name]`.

Later, I created an organization in GitHub and moved my project to that organization, including the same `gh-pages` branch. As expected, the previous Project Page URL no longer works. However, the following url does not work as well: `[organization].github.io/[project_name]`. When I check my project's settings, it says the following error in the GitHub Pages section:

*Your page is having problems building: **Validation failed: User must be a human, not an Organization***

Does this mean it is not possible at all to have a Project Page for a repository that belongs to an organization? Or did I do something wrong along the way?

**EDIT**: As a workaround, I guess I could have a [GitHub Organization Page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#user--organization-pages) in the `master` branch of a new project called `[organization]/[organization].github.io`, and then have a separate folder per project. That way I think it would be possible to emulate the `[organization].github.io/[project_name]` URL. The only disadvantage is that I would have to centralize all the projects' Pages of my organization in the same repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd assume not as organisations are treated differently to user accounts.

You could try making a page for your organisation first to see if that made a difference.

You can read how to here: https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages

Comment: Indeed, I could have a page called `[organization].github.io` (without the project name), but I would prefer to have one page per project, so that my organization is not forced to provide one public page for only one specific project. But you gave me an idea, I will edit my question.

Comment: How about you try making it then deleting it to see if you can get it to build? Or just not using it.

Comment: You could also ask GitHub support. They're really quick with replying and you'll get a better answer than from someone on here (I've had issues with them before)

Comment: Ah no I think you misunderstood me. I meant try creating the github name for your organization then try building the github page for the repository again!

Comment: That workaround would do the same thing as well though.

Comment: Yes, I did that already, I removed the previous Project page, and re-added after I moved the project to the organization. It didn't work.

Comment: The workaround worked fine. I assume this is the correct answer, that it is not possible and so a workaround like mine has to make do. Thanks.

Comment: +1 It seems that when the project page is in an org, the org has to have an org page. Note that once you create the org page, you will have to rebuild your project page (e.g. by pushing a trivial edit) to have it reappear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using CNAMEs on a project.

I needed to create a [organisation].github.io repo, and then the CNAME stuff for projects under that repo started to work.